# Send email from mIRC

Tags: email, substring, mirc

How can you make mIRC send emails?

I just learned about : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIRC_scripting_language

I would like to make somehow a script (that would be a bot?) that is watching a mIRC channel, and if somebody says something (i would use some SUBSTR if there is anything like that), then send an e-mail to a specific e-mail address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a script a person built
http://www.mircscripts.org/forums.php?cid=3&id=19972

hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

That can be usefull but that's not manage ssl support. A lot's of isp today work on smtps instead of smtp. I use myself an executable writed in delphi who support this protocol.

http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/

You can use it directly by "run XXX.exe -x xxx -x xxx -x xxx" in mirc without problem.

Comment: I believe he asked to send mail via mIRC, and not via run(cmd) command of mIRC.